# How can I fix FindElement by xpath in chrome driver misbehavior?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

FindElement by XPath function is misbehaving. It gives error for some code and works for other code.

When I give object path directly it works. But when I give it through some variable, it throws error.

It works for this

```
var usermenu = _chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/header/nav/div/div[3]/ul/li[4]/a/span"));

usermenu.Click();
```

But doesn't work for this

```
String object_id = "/html/body/div/header/nav/div/div[3]/ul/li[4]/a/span";

IWebElement btnsubmit = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(object_id));

btnsubmit.Click();
```

Comment: try to use var instead of String in String object_id

Comment: What is the error it thrown in second case?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The object was being obstructed by another modal object since my function was being called before the modal gets faded.

So I added a 2 second wait and it started working normally.

Thanks all.